# Testing Google Contextual Gadget

Tags: google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets

It is possible to test my google contextual gadget without being the Domain Administrator?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Domain Administrator to enable contextual gadget. You can check about its detail on following Google Enterprise blog: http://googleenterprise.blogspot.in/2010/05/putting-email-in-context-with-gmail.html